# Multiple environment on single K8s cluster and Nginx controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

We want to have 1 k8s cluster and to enable each developer to deploy their environment by separating developer's env by URI "/developerName", and an NS where every deployment of the app will be deployed on different NS.

The application is a legacy tomcat based web app.

I'm looking for a good approach where I can route the traffic of every developer based on URL to different deployments.

There is 1 restriction, where the application is expecting only the app name in the URL. 
i.e example.com/username/appname isn't working since the app is expecting only example.com/appname

I have deployed successfully Nginx ingress controller and checked it's working whenever I'm not using the "/developername" in the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an ingress resource. Configure each environment with different hostname:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: developer1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: developer1.mytestdomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: my-tomcat-service
              servicePort: 8080
            path: /
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - developer1.mytestdomain.com
      secretName: mysslsecret
```

Then setup a wildcard domain on `*.mytestdomai.com`. So you don't have to add a subdomain each time and environment is built. Skip the `tls` part if you don't need `https`.

Comment: I'm looking to automate things. and don't want to create a subdomain for every developer or environment I'm creating.

Comment: You don't need to. Just create a wildcard domain!

Comment: Wow, so simple. I can't understand how I missed it. I would add the last comment as part of your answer. (with the wildcard)